# Angular: Property 'go' does not exist on type 'Location'

Tags: angular, location

I'm trying to update the URL param value without page refresh while clicking the table row item  using `"location.go"`. Unfortunately I'm getting the error like `"Property 'go' does not exist on type 'Location'"`

Expert advise please?

Actual URL: `http://localhost:4200/technicalSettings/disciplines`
Expected URL without page refresh on row click: `http://localhost:4200/technicalSettings/disciplines/1109`

Version: Angular 7

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";
onRowClicked(event: any) {
    this.isRowSelected = true;
    this.selectedId = event.id;
    this.selectedItem = event;
    this.dataService.set(event);
    location.go("technicalSettings/disciplines", this.selectedId);
    //this.router.navigate(["technicalSettings/disciplines", this.selectedId]);
  }
```

Comment: Assuming location is being injected into your constructor? you're calling a local var called `location` not the injected service. Changing it to `this.location.go` should resolve the issue.

Comment: `import { Location } from '@angular/common';`

Answer (score 33):

As location service is part of angular common module. Add below import statement in your component class

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

otherwise it refer to window/document Location property.

Comment: Good catch. Be aware of it.